# Having problem using .map and anonymous function (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Created a component called "imagem" that should display images which their location are received from a array.

I'm getting error "error: bundling failed: Error: src\components\Imagem.js:Invalid call at line 10: require(name)"

also seems like map() isn't working.

- map() isn't working (don't know why), I try changing the code to display a simple Text containing {name} and it doesn't display (not running through array "locations);
  When I try with out map() using Text with just {locations[0]} it does display
- About require(), I have no idea why it isn't working:
  If I create a local variable that has '../imagem/teste.png' and use it in require(example) it works,
  If I receive it from props it doesn't

(app.js)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

import Imagem from './src/components/Imagem';

export default class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Imagem locations = {['./src/imagem/teste.png', './src/imagem/teste2.png']}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

(Imagem.js)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';


export default class Imagem extends Component{
    render(){
        const {locations} = this.props;
        return (
            locations.map(name =>{
                <Image source={require(name)} style = {styles.img}/>
            })
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    img:{
        width:30,
        height:30
    }
})
```

I expected that I could send a array of locations using my component "Imagem.js" and it would display on app screen the images.

I'm quite the noob, pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside map function, you should return something. it will add to the final result array. Seems your `Imagem` component can simply write as follows.

```
export default Imagem = (props) => (
    props.locations.map(name => <Image source={name} style = {styles.img} />)
)
```

As es6 arrow function behavior, in `locations.map(name => <Image />)` code segment will create your expected output.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Map should return new array with changed items.

```
locations.map(name => {
  return <Image source={name} style={styles.img} />
})
```

or

```
locations.map(name => <Image source={name} style={styles.img} />)
```

Remember also to add key prop to Image ;)

Comment: Thanks, it work, unfortunately stack only allows to flag one as answer, so I did the first one to answer.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Because `require` is (almost) the same as `import` you always need a static location for the loaded module. It's not working with dynamic values.
But you can try to move the require up to your `App`

```
<Imagem locations = {[require('./src/imagem/teste.png'), require('./src/imagem/teste2.png')]}/>
```

And then use it as normal property inside `Imagem`

```
locations.map(name => <Image source={name} style = {styles.img} />)
```

I'm not quite sure if this will work out of the box or you have to deal with some asynchronous stuff here.

Comment: Thanks, it work, unfortunately stack only allows to flag one as answer, so I did the first one to answer.

Thanks for the help